# Should I create an EFI Partition In The Debian Installer?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, debian, efi

In the Debian Installer after you are done partitioning I was asked if I wanted to create an EFI partition. I do have Windows 7 already installed in EFI mode apparently (that was a mess up on my part) so I guess I am asking weather or not I should create a new one for Debian and how exactly I would install Debian in EFI mode (I've always used BIOS).

My current partition table (from Windows):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've already got an EFI System Partition (ESP) on what Windows is calling Disk 0 (probably `/dev/sda` under Linux), so it's probably safer to use that than to create a new ESP. IIRC, in Debian's installer, you need to select that partition and tell the installer that it's the "EFI boot partition." Also IIRC, you don't explicitly set a mount point, although the installer will configure it to be mounted at `/boot/efi`.