# EFI partition not found

Tags: windows-8, debian, efi

I’m instaling Debian in a laptop that already has Windows 8 installed. Everything went right but when I finish the partioning, a message says:

> EFI Partition not found, do you want to continue?

And I don’t know what to do then.

Comment: Did you allow `Debian` to create the required EFI partition?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You should have done it when Debian was being [installed](http://superuser.com/questions/619185/should-i-create-an-efi-partition-in-the-debian-installer?rq=1)

Comment: I didn't finished the installing, because I don't know what to do then.

Comment: I provided a link to some additional information about the EFI partition and Debian installation process.  here is some more [information](http://superuser.com/questions/731016/efi-not-found-when-installing-debian-7-4-beside-windows-8-1?rq=1) it sounds like your EFI partition is missing.  Can you confirm that's the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you simply didn't tell the Debian installer to use your existing EFI System Partition (ESP). If you go back into the partitioning tool, you should see a small (100-500MiB, usually) FAT partition that will probably be flagged with the name "EFI," "EFI boot," "EFI system," or something similar. Use the Debian partitioning tool to tell the installer to use that partition as the EFI [system/boot] partition. (Sorry the naming is uncertain; the partition is officially known as an EFI System Partition, but many tools deviate from that name. I believe Debian has recently come more in line with the official name, but I don't know if what you're using has this very recent change.)

If your disk does *not* have an existing ESP, then you should stop and consider how your computer is currently booting Windows. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for information on how to make that determination. If you're booting Windows in BIOS mode, then you should not be attempting to install Debian in EFI mode, since getting your dual-boot working will be difficult. Computers that shipped with Windows 8 or 8.1 almost always boot in EFI mode, but it's not 100% clear that yours came with Windows 8, so it could be booting in BIOS mode for all I know. In most cases you can control the boot mode of an external medium (such as whatever's holding your Debian installer) by using the computer's built-in boot manager. External media will normally show up twice, once with "UEFI" in the description and once without. Selecting the "UEFI" entry boots in EFI mode, but the other entry boots in BIOS mode.